# MPMoviePlayerController replay video

Tags: ios

I want to display a button that gives the option to the user to restart a video in a MPMoviePlayerController at any time, even while the video is playing. I tried this but it has no effect:

```
-(IBAction)ReloadVideo:(id)sender{

[moviePlayer play];

}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should call first `[moviePlayer stop]` this will:

> stops playback of the current item and resets the playhead to the
>   start of the item. Calling the play method again initiates playback
>   from the beginning of the item.

(From apple docs)